# Attachment Fields Missing

Tags: couchdb

I'm putting together a simple application using couchdb which primarily stores files.  I noticed when I ran a test that extra fields I'd supplied when uploading a file as an attachment do not get stored.

I created a document with this snippet of its _attachments:

```
"_attachments": {
    'f5asQDuG': {   
        'content_type': 'application/pdf',
        'data': ... 
        'length': 1049191,
        'original_filename': '05_50_Delinquency Policy 2010.pdf'
    }, ...
}
```

However if I browse the db using futon I get this data back:

```
"_attachments": {
    "f5asQDuG": {
        "content_type": "application/pdf",
        "revpos": 1,
        "length": 1049191,
        "stub": true
    }, ...
}
```

If I try `attachments=true` in an HTTP GET, I don't get anything different except it's no longer stubbed.

Is couchdb dropping the data, or is it simply hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got sick of waiting so I dug around in the bug tracker for couchdb at Apache.  This is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-259) and at this time it looks like they're scheduling it for the 1.2 release.